# How to decode the URL with \3a and \3d into a valid URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decoding

I have image urls coming from FB like this

[image]

I want to decode this using Python

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

unquote('https\3a //scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276224522_526712219026525_574582522520082091_n.jpg?stp\3d cp0_dst-jpg_e15_p160x160_q65\26 _nc_cat\3d 101\26 ccb\3d 1-7\26 _nc_sid\3d 110474\26 efg\3d eyJpIjoidCJ9\26 _nc_ohc\3d GYg2KoaviA4AX_3gvNu\26 _nc_ht\3d scontent-yyz1-1.xx\26 oh\3d 00_AT9qampQP8qPyoKOJo4hW9hKRepgLX4krubFMFteOMaizA\26 oe\3d 62F8E686')
```

It returns this

```
'https\x03a //scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276224522_526712219026525_574582522520082091_n.jpg?stp\x03d cp0_dst-jpg_e15_p160x160_q65\x16 _nc_cat\x03d 101\x16 ccb\x03d 1-7\x16 _nc_sid\x03d 110474\x16 efg\x03d eyJpIjoidCJ9\x16 _nc_ohc\x03d GYg2KoaviA4AX_3gvNu\x16 _nc_ht\x03d scontent-yyz1-1.xx\x16 oh\x03d 00_AT9qampQP8qPyoKOJo4hW9hKRepgLX4krubFMFteOMaizA\x16 oe\x03d 62F8E686'
```

How do I decode it to proper URL?

Answer (score 1):

A crude solution that replaces the characters in the string

```py
def parse_fb_url(string):
    """parses facebook cdn urls"""

    # convert to raw string
    raw_string = string.encode("unicode_escape").decode()

    # manual inspection of the url reveals the encoding
    replacement_map = {
        r"\x03a": ":",
        r"\x03d": "=",
        r"\x16": "&",
        r" ": "",
    }

    for key, replacement in replacement_map.items():
        raw_string = raw_string.replace(key, replacement)

    return raw_string


string = "https\3a //scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276224522_526712219026525_574582522520082091_n.jpg?stp\3d cp0_dst-jpg_e15_p160x160_q65\26 _nc_cat\3d 101\26 ccb\3d 1-7\26 _nc_sid\3d 110474\26 efg\3d eyJpIjoidCJ9\26 _nc_ohc\3d GYg2KoaviA4AX_3gvNu\26 _nc_ht\3d scontent-yyz1-1.xx\26 oh\3d 00_AT9qampQP8qPyoKOJo4hW9hKRepgLX4krubFMFteOMaizA\26 oe\3d 62F8E686"
parsed_string = parse_fb_url(string)
print(parsed_string)
```

This gave me the following output:

```
https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276224522_526712219026525_574582522520082091_n.jpg?stp=cp0_dst-jpg_e15_p160x160_q65&_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=110474&efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&_nc_ohc=GYg2KoaviA4AX_3gvNu&_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.xx&oh=00_AT9qampQP8qPyoKOJo4hW9hKRepgLX4krubFMFteOMaizA&oe=62F8E686
```

[image: the image in the url]